# If else in loop issue

Tags: r, loops, if-statement

Given a toy code

```
row1 <- c(1,1,1,0,0,0, NA, NA)
row2 <- c(1,1,1,0,0,0, NA, NA)

test <- t(data.frame(row1, row2))

for (j in 1:length(test)) {
  binary <- test[, j]


  if (binary[1] == 1 &
      binary[2] == 1)  {
    print("A")
  }
  else if (binary[1] == 1 &
           binary[2] == 0) {
    print("B")
  }
  else (is.na(binary[1]) |
          is.na(binary[2])) {
    print("NA")
  }
}
```

The espected print out would be:

> A, A, A, B, B, B, NA, NA

However, it won't work and I can't see the mistake in the loop.

Comment: I would recommend running little pieces of code to make sure they are what you think. For example, `length(test)` and `1:length(test) - 2` are probably both bugs. (If `test` was a data frame, it would only be one bug, but as a matrix it is two.)

Comment: Did you mean “regular” and “irregular” instead of “A” and “B”? And why is this the expected output? The reason isn’t apparent.

Comment: Sorry guys, was a typo mistake. I edited the code.
I assume that I use else if wrong but can't see the syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly,

```
> test[, 4]
row1 row2 
   0    0
```

So it should never print `B`. Secondly, you have this issue later

```
> NA == 1
[1] NA
```

You should check for `NA`'s first.

Answer (score 0):

That loop will not print the structure you need. start by fixing your j in the loop , if you are looping over the number of columns:

```
for (j in 1:ncol(test)) {
binary <- test[ ,j]
```

if so, you will never see a 1 and 0 together, and will never get a B

thirdly your output will be printed line by line, vertically not horizontally.